# Is there any way to add more options in Filters of @mui/x-data-grid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

```
function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      <GridToolbarExport />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  )
}
```

Inside these filters option, I want to add extra Not equal option how can I add this?

If possible, post the answer with code. I'll be very thankful.